How stop spam letters from users ? Using php and mysql
How solve this problem ?  I have a table name guest book and when users  type spam letters like this words AAAAAAAA ........ they let my page out of size original! how can fix it .. Notice im using dreamweaver Cs6
Don't have any idea what can i do for this !!

have you tried Regex?

Does this answer your question? Regex to prevent the same character from appearing more than 3 times in a row - It is a JS solution but the regex remains the same for all languages.

You said they let my page out of size original!
If I correctly understand your real need:
you may use word-wrap to avoid the formatting problem
<style>

.fixedwidth1 {  
    width: 200px; 
    word-wrap: break-word; }

</style>



<div class=fixedwidth1>Some text</div>

<div class=fixedwidth1>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>

The result will be:

